# Python Interprter error while loading JSON file using json.load()

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

This is my python code for parsing a JSON file.

```
import os
import argparse
import json
import datetime


ResultsJson = "sample.json"
try:
    with open(ResultsJson, 'r') as j:
        jsonbuffer = json.load(j)
        result_data = json.loads(jsonbuffer)
        print("Just after loading json")
except Exception as e:
        print(e, exc_info=True)
```

I get an error like in the snapshot attached below.
[image]

I'm also attaching the JSON file "sample.json" that I'm using here.
**sample.json**

```
{
  "idx": 1,
  "timestamp": 1562781093.1182132,
  "machine_id": "tool_2",
  "part_id": "af71ce94-e9b2-47c0-ab47-a82600616b6d",
  "image_id": "14cfb9e9-1f38-4126-821b-284d7584b739",
  "cam_sn": "camera-serial-number",
  "defects": [
    {
      "type": 0,
      "tl": [169, 776],
      "br": [207, 799]
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "tl": [404, 224],
      "br": [475, 228]
    },
    {
      "type": 1,
      "tl": [81, 765],
      "br": [130, 782]
    }
  ],
  "display_info": [
    {
      "info": "DEFECT DETECTED",
      "priority": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Not sure what I missed here. I'm very new to Python (Coming from C++ background). Please be easy on me if I've missed something basic.

Comment: `json.load(j)` already loads your json and transforms it to a python dictionary. When you do json.loads() it pretty much means json.load_string (as opposed to loading from file) so it expects a string but receives a dictionary. If you want to first read the file to a string you should use something like `textstring=f.read()` or smtg like that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this line:

```
result_data = json.loads(jsonbuffer)
```

...because `jsonbuffer` is the result of `json.load`, so it's *already* the result of parsing the JSON file. In your case it's a Python dictionary, but `json.loads` expects a string, so you get an error.

Also, as the second error message says, `exc_info` is not a valid keyword argument of the `print` function. If you wanted to print the exception, just do `print(e)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either:

```
with open(ResultsJson, 'r') as j:
    result_data = json.load(j)
    print("Just after loading json")
```

Or:

```
with open(ResultsJson, 'r') as j:
    result_data = json.loads(j.read())
    print("Just after loading json")
```

The json.load() internally calls the json.loads() function